# R - Barchart plots empty values when using the "groups" argument

Tags: r, bar-chart, spaces

I'm plotting the amount of organisms found in several samples at different depths in the ocean using barchart.

```
barchart(density~depth, groups=species,
     main=list(label="Species composition in Hinlopen",cex=2),
     ylab="Species density(n pr. m3)", 
     data=species_density_depths_hinlopen,
     origin=0,
     auto.key=list(space="top",columns=3, title="Species"),
     par.settings = my_settings)
```

This gives me some nice bars showing species composition grouped by depth.
But, not all organisms was found at every depth and barchart still makes an empty space for where that organisms bar "should've" been.
Is there any way of telling barchart not to plot these empty spaces?
Here is how it looks at the moment:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there are several empty spaces between the bars.

**EDIT**
Recreatable example:

```
library(lattice)
dep <- c(replicate(10,10),replicate(10,20))
sp <- c(replicate(7,"Krill"),replicate(7, "Calanus"),replicate(6,"Ctenophora"))
dens <- rnorm(20,mean=5)

animals <- data.frame(species=sp,density=dens,depth=as.factor(dep))

barchart(density~depth, groups=species,
         main=list(label="Species composition in Kongsfjorden (KB3)",cex=2),
         ylab="Species density(n pr. m3)", 
         data=animals)
```

Comment: I'm not certain at the moment *how*, but why do you want to exclude it? The absence of data at different depths is perhaps itself interesting. (Allow me refer to the movie *Contact* and its ["eighteen hours" of recorded static](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884/quotes#qt0379375).)

Comment: I agree that the absence might be interesting. But it does not need to be represented by an empty space that takes up room.
I'd rather have no bar and no empty space. That way the bars that ARE present can be wider and easier to see.

My problem is even more problematic with other locations that have even more species present in the total water collumn. There are so many bars that each bar becomes very small, and therefor removing the empty spaces is even more important.

Come to think of it, since there are no labels under the empty spaces, you don't know what it was supposed to be anyway.

Comment: It is an interesting problem. I think you will need to create a new factor variable that is a cross-product of the other two, drop the empty levels, then order and color them yourself.

Comment: Noted. I don't know of any *automated* method for doing this, so you may need to break the data down yourself and use side-by-side barplots. I'd recommend using `layout()` or perhaps even `par(fig)` if you're adventurous. The former is much easier to use but doesn't allow the facade of a single plot, whereas the latter gives you plenty of rope. Check out [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) for a comparison.

Comment: You could also try `ggplot`, `library(ggplot2) ggplot(data=animals,aes(x=depth,y=density,fill=species))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())`. Just not sure what you want the height of the bars to be since for each depth you have multiple densities for each species

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a new factor that is a cross-product of the two you are displaying, then after populating it drop the empty levels, then plot it as a bar graph while coloring it yourself.

A lot of work really. Maybe someone knows a better idea. If you post sample data someone will probably take a crack at it.

Comment: Added some sample data to my original post just now.